# Passing a Complex Parameter into a Query in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angular-resource

I have seen 100 examples of passing an ID into $resource.get() in order to query information out of a back-end in Angular.  What I have not been able to find is how to pass a complex object.

If I have a table of objects to return, and I wish to run a search against them using multiple items of filter, I need to pass those items as parameters or as one complex parameter.  For example, say I have a table of people's names and their cities, states, etc.  I want to be able to say something like this:

```
var myResource = $resource(url);
myResource.get({name : "Mike", state : "Texas"});
```

The return may be a single row or multiple rows.  But the point is how do I get the parameters off to the API call?

The way I have other methods set up that are simpler is by creating a repository in which I return like so:

```
return resource('/api/broker/productionInfo/');
```

Then in my API I do this (after the [RoutePrefix("api/broker")] setup:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("productionInfo")]
public IHttpActionResult GetProductions()
{}
```

That's all awesome but I want to be able to add the search criteria in the repository call and then in the API method (i.e. extract from a querystring or however it is to be passed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I'm seeing that you're missing is a `[FromUri]` decorate attribute, in your ***GetProduction*** API method. Since `Get` supports only params binding through a query string *(no body binding)*.

Your params:

```
options: {
    StartDate: _startDate
    EndDate: _endDate
    TextSearch: "some search query....",
    Page: 1,
    PageSize: 25,
    et...
}
```

Then, calling your repository from your controller:

```
repository.get(options).$promise.then(function (data) {
    // data =  response payload from backend
});
```

reposiroty

```
....
    return resource('/api/broker/productionInfo/');
....
```

API

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("productionInfo")]
public IHttpActionResult GetProductions([FromUri] SearchCriteriaModel criteria) {
    ....
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems like my missing [FromUri] attribute was the difference-maker.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, you just want to pass additional parameters into an angular resource `get` request. It is as simple as what you have already suggested:

```
resource.get({id: 1, custom_param_1: "param1", custom_param_2: "param2"});
```

This would result in an http request that looks like this:

```
/resource/1?custom_param_1=param1&custom_param_2=param2
```

You can then extract these parameters on the API side of things.

Something to note is that `get` requests have a maximum length, and if you are attaching lots of different parameters to the request, it may be better to use a `post` or `put` instead.